# Flutter codesign error with iOS and MacOS

Tags: ios, flutter, macos-sonoma

When I try to run my Flutter app on an iOS simulator or MacOS, it gives me the following errors below. However, on the Android emulator, it works. I tried to run `flutter clean` but it doesn't solve the issue. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate for development. How can I solve this?

iOS error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            2.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Target debug_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Failed to codesign /Users/julian/Desktop/flutter_projects/chat_app/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flutter.framework/Flutter with identity -.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.
```

Comment: Flutter doctor tells me everything is fine:

julian@Julians-MacBook-Pro chat_app % flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.5, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale en-DE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2023.2.2)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is open Runner.xcodeproj in the ios folder with Xcode, select "Runner" on the top left, then select Signing and Capabilities. There under "Team" you need to add your Apple developer account (It doesn't need to be a paid account).

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this issue, even on a fresh new project. I lost the issue link, but I guess it had to do with creating/having a project in a cloud folder, for me it was iCloud. Once I created a new project in a non-cloud folder the app worked, then i moved my existing project to a non-cloud folder it worked!